# How do I alternate between using the rising and falling edge of a button interrupt in STM32F4?

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32f4

Button presses must alternate between two states:

1.) LED will turn ON in the rising edge of the button and keeps ON in
the falling edge.

2.) LED will turn OFF in the falling edge of the next button press.

[Button and LED Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmiPq.jpg)

This is the main function of what I tried but the LED turns off only on button press:

```
volatile unsigned int pressed;
volatile unsigned int state;
int main(void){
    pressed = 0;
    state = 0;
    LD_Init();
    Interrupt_Init();
    /* Loop forever */
    while(1) {
        if (pressed) {
            if (state == 0) {
                EXTI->FTSR |= (1<<13); // Enable EXTI on Falling edge
                EXTI->RTSR &= ~(1<<13); // Disable EXTI on Rising edge
            }
            if  (state == 1){
                EXTI->FTSR &= ~(1<<13); // Disable EXTI on Falling edge
                EXTI->RTSR |= (1<<13); // Enable EXTI on Rising edge
            }
            GPIOA->ODR ^= (1<<5);
            pressed = 0;
            state = !state;
        }
    }
}
void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){
    pressed = 1;
    EXTI->PR |= (1<<13); // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt
}
```

Comment: To go from pressed to unpressed (unpressed to pressed) there is a falling (rising) edge in the button, i.e. you have to ignore one falling (rising) edge for each state change.

Comment: If you could see it, the LED is flashing as fast as it can, but only when the button is pressed! Think: "was not pressed, now it is" and "was pressed, now it isn't"... What does this suggest to you? (Further, no button is perfect... Are you accounting for "bounce"?)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please add in which way your program is not working? what do you observe?

Comment: Your flag `pressed` does not reflect whether the button is pressed. It reflects that a rising or falling edge was detected, depending on EXT interrupt configuration.

Comment: Buttons don't work this way. You need to implement "de-bouncing" - which ought to be mentioned in any embedded systems beginner learning material. There's no point in worrying about application-tied functionality if you haven't even got a working driver with de-bouncing implemented.

Comment: using EXTI for a button is the worst design decision taken

Comment: @cafce25 does that mean there are 4 states or am I using the EXTI wrong?

Comment: @0___________ our instructor gave us this problem after giving a very simple and brief example so I just based my solution off of that. What is the better way of doing it?